# How to use java.util.Date as a map key in Groovy

Tags: java, grails, collections, groovy, maps

here's my problem: I am trying to fill the following map:

```
class Driver extends User{


final UserRole role = UserRole.DRIVER
Map<Date, Route> routes = [:]

static hasMany = [
    assignedJobs:Job
]

static mappedBy = [
    assignedJobs:'assignedUser'
]
static constraints = {
}
}
```

Here's the code filling it:

```
def private addStationToRoute(driver, station){
    def route = driver.routes.get(station?.estimatedArrival.clearTime())
    if(route == null)
        route = new Route()
//      route.stations.add(station)
//      route.stations.sort({it.position})
    def key = station?.estimatedArrival.clearTime()
    driver.routes.put(key, route)
}
```

which leads me to a ClassCastException:

```
java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Line | Method
->>   97 | $tt__save in elektrova.JobController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

after some research I found that putting the key in paranthesis should do the trick
(sources:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections   The Maps section
http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/11/groovy-goodness-complex-keys-in-maps.html

which lead me to trying this:

```
def private addStationToRoute(driver, station){
    def route = driver.routes.get(station?.estimatedArrival.clearTime())
    if(route == null)
        route = new Route()
//      route.stations.add(station)
//      route.stations.sort({it.position})
    def key = station?.estimatedArrival.clearTime()
    driver.routes[(key)] = (route)
}
```

Any suggestions what to do?
(BTW, I tried changing it to key.toString(), which makes the exception disappear)
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
The error occurs while saving:

```
@Transactional
def save(Job jobInstance) {
    if (jobInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        logNotFound("save", Job.class)

        return
    }

    setSaveConditions(jobInstance)
    setUpdateConditions(jobInstance)
    jobService.createStationsForJob(jobInstance)
    if(jobInstance.assignedUser)
        jobService.addStationsToRoute(jobInstance)
    jobInstance.validate()
    if (jobInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond jobInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }
    println 'routes: ' + jobInstance.assignedUser.routes.toString()
    jobInstance.save flush:true
    println 'routes: ' + jobInstance.assignedUser.routes.toString()
    logSaving(jobInstance)
    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
                message(code: 'job.label', default: 'Job'),
                jobInstance.encodeAsHTML()
            ])
            redirect jobInstance
        }
        '*' { respond jobInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

grails tells me error line is the one containing jobInstance.save flush:true. The jobInstance has a driver attribute, which contains the  Map. When I use the String representation the same error occurs for the route object:

```
Message: elektrova.Route cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Line | Method
->>   97 | $tt__save in elektrova.JobController$$EOZiJFlq
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

and when I use the String representation of the route the saving is done. But why in the world would the Map expect two Strings?

EDIT2:

The Domain classes:

```
class Job implements Serializable{


JobStatus status = JobStatus.ACTIVE
Station startStation
Station endStation


String containerNumber
String loadingIndicator = false
String containerISO
String oversizeIndicator = false
Double grossWeight = 0
Boolean nonOperatingReeferIndicator = false
String iReference
String consigneeReference
String quayAccountNumber
String carrierCode
String bookingReference
String releaseNumber
String transportMeansIdentification
Boolean trainTransportIndicator = false
Boolean dangerousGoodsIndicator = false
String gegisReference
Boolean customsIndicator = false
String registrationNumber
String registrationPositon


Date creationTimeStamp
User updateUser
Date updateTimeStamp

boolean deleted = false

static belongsTo = [
    hauler:Hauler,
    assignedUser:Driver,
    creationUser:Disponent
]




static constraints = {
    hauler(blank:false, nullable:false)
    status(blank:false, nullable:false)
    endStation(nullable:true)
    startStation(nullable:true)     

    assignedUser(nullable:true)
    containerNumber(nullable:true)
    containerISO(nullable:true)
    iReference(nullable:true)
    consigneeReference(nullable:true)
    quayAccountNumber(nullable:true)
    carrierCode(nullable:true)
    bookingReference(nullable:true)
    releaseNumber(nullable:true)
    transportMeansIdentification(nullable:true)
    gegisReference(nullable:true)
    registrationNumber(nullable:true)
    registrationPositon(nullable:true)


    updateUser(nullable:true)
    updateTimeStamp(nullable:true)

    creationTimeStamp(blank:false, nullable:false)
    creationUser(blank:false, nullable:false)
}



def cancel(){
    this.status = JobStatus.CANCELLED
}

def finish(){
    this.status = JobStatus.DONE
}

//  @Override
//  def encodeAsHTML(){
 ////       destination.locationName + " (" + containerNumber + ") " + plannedArrivalTime.toString()
//  }
}

class Route {

//  List<Station> stations = []
//  
//  static belongsTo = [
//      hauler:Hauler,
//      driver:Driver
//  ]

//  static hasMany = [
//      jobs:Job
//  ]
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Date as a map key as it's mutable :-/

Comment: You only need paranthesis if you are using the initialization syntax, e.g. `routes = [(key): value]`. Groovy should not be the problem (you can do this in Groovy, besides the problem tim_yates noted). Your error is coming from grails. What are you doing with the map? Is Driver a domain class?

Comment: Yes it is, the problem occurs when saving the Driver class

Comment: How are all these domain objects mapped to the database? this is probably an issue occurring when GORM is trying to convert your domain objects into their database representation

Comment: I pretty much used groovys default mapping, added the domain classes to the main question

Comment: `97 | $tt__save in elektrova.JobController` Your error seems to happen when GORM try to save your object. You map should go to the database? If not, make it transient.

Comment: Yes, the map should go into the DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use a date as a map key as you are doing so in your declaration of the map but your question is really about fixing a problem with the storage of it in a database.